# How to fail a test after a timeout is exceeded in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

In JUnit 4 the "timeout" annotation parameter can be used to force a test to stop after the given amount of time:

```java
@Test(timeout=100)
public void infinity() {
   while(true);
}
```

How can this be done in JUnit 5?

Closely related to (and code taken from) [timeout parameter for Annotation Type Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015032/timeout-parameter-for-annotation-type-test), but for JUnit 5.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The strict equivalent of the `timeout` attribute  is the declarative `@Timeout` annotation.
[From the JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts) :

> The `@Timeout` annotation allows one to declare that a test, test
> factory, test template, or lifecycle method should fail if its
> execution time exceeds a given duration. The time unit for the
> duration defaults to seconds but is configurable.

For example :

```
@Test
@Timeout(value = 100, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
void infinity() { 
  // fails if execution time exceeds 100 milliseconds
  //...
}
```

[`Assertions.assertTimeout()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertTimeout(java.time.Duration,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) and [`Assertions.assertTimeoutPreemptively()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertTimeoutPreemptively(java.time.Duration,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) are new concepts introduced in JUnit 5 (not existing in JUnit 4).
These are alternatives to `@Timeout` that narrow the timeout to a specific set of statements : these defined in the `Executable` or in the `Supplier` passed as parameter.
These two methods (with a very close name) address the same overall goal but with a subtle difference.
`assertTimeoutPreemptively()`  preemptively aborts the `Executable/Supplier` if the timeout occurs while `assertTimeout()` does not.
To achieve it, `assertTimeoutPreemptively()` executes the provided `Executable/Supplier` in a different thread than that of the calling code while `assertTimeout()` executes it in the same thread.

Warning from the official documentation :
Code/libraries relying on the `java.lang.ThreadLocal` storage for the test execution setup/teardown may have undesirable side effects with `assertTimeoutPreemptively()` since that executes the provided statements in a different thread.

Comment: A global (configurable) timeout that can be put in a base test class from which other classes extend  so that rouge tests are killed off is very much required in JUnit 5 Jupiter.. it was a very useful feature in JUnit 4.x

Answer (score 9):

Use the `assertTimeoutPreemptively` static assertion from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`:

```java
@Test
public void infinity() {
    assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofMillis(100), () -> {
        while (true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers which specify a timeout for a specific test (per the OP request), beginning in JUnit 5.5 it is also possible to configure a global timeout, a useful option instead of adding the `@Timeout` annotation to every method.

Per the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts), which documents the syntax in the other answers:

> configuration parameters can be used to specify global timeouts for all methods of a certain category unless they or an enclosing test class is annotated with @Timeout

For example, this would set a global timeout of 500 milliseconds for all testable and lifecycle methods:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.timeout.default = 500 ms
```

The timeouts can be more narrowly scoped, for example just `@Test` methods:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.timeout.testtemplate.method.default = 500 ms
```

The `@Timeout` annotation described in the other answers will override these defaults if it is used.