# JUnit 5, Test not failing despite @Timeout

Tags: java, junit5

I wonder what I am missing, but my JUnit 5 test with @Timeout is not failing when it should.

Here is my test class:

```
package tests;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;

import main.SomeClass;

class SomeUtilsTest {

    @Test
    @Timeout (5)
    void testSomething() {
        assertEquals (1, SomeClass.doSomething());
    }

}
```

And here is the class that I am testing:

```
package main;

public class SomeClass {

    public static Integer doSomething() {
        while (true);
    }

}
```

It should fail after five seconds, but no matter how long I wait, the test never fails; the program continues to "run", and I can only manually terminate it.

Comment: Which exact JUnit version are you using? How exactly do you start the JUnit test?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2087) github issue discusses the same problem and suggests a few workarounds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fail a test after a timeout is exceeded in JUnit 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116801/how-to-fail-a-test-after-a-timeout-is-exceeded-in-junit-5)

Comment: @laszlok I fail to see how this question is a duplicate of that question. The OP is already using `@Timeout` as suggested in the answers to that question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel please read the question and its accepted answer more carefully. `@Timeout` is used in the question there, and using it is unsurprisingly _not_ suggested in the answer.

Comment: @laszlok I have read the question: question asks what the replacement is for the old JUnit 4 `timeout` **parameter** of the `@Test` annotation (so it mention JUnit 5 `@Timeout` at all), and the accepted answer refers to using `@Timeout` or `assertTimeout` or `assertTimeoutPreemptively()`. Neither that question asks nor its answers answer why `@Timeout` might not be working, and as such it is not a duplicate, even if using `assertTimeout` or `assertTimeoutPreemptively()` would be the solution.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I guess it depends on your interpretation - mine was that the question asks "how to do exactly the same thing as JUnit 4 @Timeout" and the answer clearly explains that the way to do it is `assertTimeoutPreemptively` (while also mentioning other, similar things that OP might prefer to use). Anyway, since you disagree, I've added a substantial answer here now.

Answer (score 2):

A test configured with the @Timeout annotation will fail if its execution time exceeds a given duration. If the timeout is exceeded, the thread executing the test is interrupted from another thread, and is then expected to complete.

In your case, the interrupt does nothing, as you aren't performing any blocking operations, so your test continues to run forever.

What you can do instead is use one of the `assertTimeoutPreemptively` methods - [see the documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html). In your example:

`assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofSeconds(5), SomeClass::doSomething);`

Do be aware that this will use a separate thread to execute `SomeClass::doSomething`. It is therefore up to you to ensure that everything you need (for the actual computation in the separate thread, or for subsequent assertions in the main thread) is correctly visible.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the code below was the solution. It seems like `Timeout` doesn't work as expected when a long running computation and the code responsible for halting this computation run in the same thread.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout.ThreadMode.SEPARATE_THREAD;

class SomeUtilsTest {

    @Test
    @Timeout(value = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS, threadMode = SEPARATE_THREAD)
    void testSomething() {
        assertEquals (1, SomeClass.doSomething());
    }
}
```